# Problem with Schema Model type when using PrismaJS and NestJS

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, prisma

I have Members model in my Prisma schema as follows:
[image]

where `branch` is a relation to **Branch** model with `branchId` foreign key.

I'm using this schema in members services as follows:
[image]

Where `lastBranchFromMember` returns user with populated **branch** in select.
The problem occurs when I want to access branch name in controllers but **branch** doesn't get recognize in controllers, I can only select `branchId` or `branchOrder` when I type `lastBranchFromMember.branch.name`

[image]

Did I do something wrong in my Prisma Schema? or do I have to do something else?

Thank you for your help.

Here I attach exported prisma client file for Member where `branch` does not exists but still can be access with `{ include: { branch: true }}` I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `{ include: { branch: true } }` and the return type is incorrect. It should be the following:

```
import { Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

type MemberWithBranch = Prisma.MemberGetPayload<{
  include: { branch: true }
}>

async lastBranchFromMember(branchId: string): Promise<MemberWithBranch> {
  // function
}
```

Comment: I thought it's automatically added Promise<MemberType>?

Comment: No. `Member` doesn't contain `branch`. You need to add a type like the above.